# construction of 25 delta butterfly

Tags: options, option-strategies

Could anyone explain why the 25-delta butterfly strategy is constructed by 0.5*(25-delta call + 25-delta put) - ATM straddle?

Especially, what the term "25-delta" represents in "25-delta butterfly strategy"?

Comment: 25 delta represent the strike at which the delta of the option is equal to 0.25 (call) and -0.25(put). It is just one way of measuring money-ness, other would be, say log of F/K (forward price divided by strike).

Comment: "25 delta" is an abbreviation for "delta = 0.25". The first time I heard it I thought how can a delta equal 25, the maximum is 1.

Comment: Haha, even I had the same thought when I heard it for the first time. Now calling 0.25 delta looks odd and 25 delta looks natural.